# c# what is the difference between "!" operator and "?" operator?

Tags: c#, null, nullable

What is the difference between these operators?

```
var c = foo?.Prop1;
```

---

```
var c = foo!.Prop1;
```

Btw, `Prop1` is an `int`.

Comment: `!` tells the compiler: "trust me, this isn't null" but at runtime an exception can happen if you've lied. `?` handles a possible null value, so that everything after it is also null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well `?` is *null conditional* when `!` is *null forgiving* operators:

- `?.` *in case* of `full` is `null` do nothing (or return `null`)
- `!.` *do not believe* that `foo` can ever be `null` and stop warning me.

So if `foo` is `null`

```
var c = foo?.Prop1; // c will be null (c will be of type int?)
var d = foo!.Prop1; // exception will be thrown (d is int)
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that if Prop1 is an int, than c is  a nullable int and d is an int .